# Secure ASP.NET MVC calls to controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Quick question;

Giving the controller User and the and function Get someone could call;

mydomain.com/user/get and access the functionality over there.

What are the best practices to allow only my application to be able to call that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Decorating the Action Method with the  [ChildActionOnly] attribute will ensure that the Action Method on a controller cannot be directly invoked by a user entering a URL. EG

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult _CantNavigateHere()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Hi Judo,It works if the call is done from a controller. I call some controller funcitonality from jQuery using $.ajax, and when i do, if the controller action is decorated like you proposed i get a 500 error back. How can i be able to call this action from jquery and still have it decorated like that?

Comment: For ajax scenarios you will need to implement an [AjaxOnly] attribute, there is a simple demo here http://helios.ca/2009/05/27/aspnet-mvc-action-filter-ajax-only-attribute/ .

Comment: But does this mean that anyone could call it using ajax?

Comment: It would be a bit of a hack, but yes it could theoretically be called using Ajax. These filters are more for separation of concerns and consistency than security. If there are security issues with accessing the controller then the controller probably exposes too much. Perhaps post some more of your code.

Comment: Well, let's say that i have a controller called Save and an action called Transaction, and that i pass to that action a couple of string parameters; and i'm using jQuery ajax ($.ajax) to post back to the server, a pretty common scenario these days; i believe there's got to be a way to secure that, to allow only mu application to make use of that functionality, isn't it?

Comment: Authentication and Authorization are there to limit the access to this functionality, and data checks should be used to ensure the integrity of the data. If it is a controller it is intended to be invoked with a user's action, if not it should be in the model. Save and Transaction actually sound more like they should be in the model not the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AntiForgeryToken with MVC3 and Ajax.

This is how I do it. (this isn't foolproof of course, but adds another layer of security)

On your view, anywhere, output:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

And in your Ajax call include this value in the post variables like:

```
$.post("/Controller/Action/",
                { 'id': var_id, '__RequestVerificationToken': $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val() }, 
                function (data) { /* handle request */ });
```

And in your Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Action(int id) {..}
```

Besides this, you can also do a check for the referring host and reject any host that doesn't match your domain.  This can be spoofed, but again, is just another layer to add.